# Getting a resolution error on Chrome and Firefox for C9 app. Not sure how to resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, screen-resolution

Okay, I'm having an issue regrading screen size resolution and I have no idea how to go about it because I'm still not completely sure what the issue is. 
So, I am designing a Voting App that allows people to create a poll and then vote on it. The page where users cast a vote is where I am having an issue. The page looks like below at 1024 x 768 resolution[image: This is the screenshot of the app at 1024 x 768]

When the page is at the resolution mentioned above, I can't click on any of the radio buttons or the submit button. However, when I resize the window to 800 x 600, I can click on the radio buttons fine.

Also, when I submit my option, I create a chart based on the polls. The chart displays fine when the screen resolution is 800 x 600. Screenshot is below

[image: Screenshot of app with graph]

If I resize the above screenshot to anything above 800 x 600, to say 1024 x 600, the graph overlaps the radio buttons. Screenshot for that is below

[image: Overlapping screenshot]

Why is this happening? The app was working fine a few hours ago, and nothing was changed between then and now. I am using Bootstrap and CSS for styling my elements. I am including the CSS code below

```
.custom-div{
    display:none;
}
.col-md-10{
    height:auto;
    min-height:500px;
}
.ChartDiv{
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-250px;
    position:relative;
}
#myChart{
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    padding:0;
    margin:auto;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.submit-wrapper{
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: `The app was working fine a few hours ago, and nothing was changed between then and now` - clearly something HAS changed, programs don't change the way they run on a whim

Comment: @JaromandaX - Hey, what I meant was, I haven't changed any of the code between then and now. I make sure to test the code every few lines of code I write. None of the code I even wrote towards the end of my last session had anything to do with display. It had more to do with inner functionality.

Comment: Instead of using class ChartDiv why don't you use bootstrap class col-sm-6 and put all the contents inside a div in it.

Comment: @SafalPillai - Thanks, that worked like a charm!

Comment: Please mark it as the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using class ChartDiv why don't you use bootstrap class col-sm-6 and put all the contents inside a div in it.